# How do i test this model on a single png file

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I want to try this model on a single png file for prediction.
I am very new to this field.
This is for study purpose.

i have tried model(filename) 
and i get output like

> > Tensor("sequential_1_36/activation_6/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)Tensor("sequential_1_36/activation_6/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

if i could predict the class names.

```
   train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(img_width, 
img_height,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=    ['accuracy',precision,recall,fbeta_score])




 history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,samples_per_epoch=nb_train 


 _samples,nb_epoch=nb_epoch,validation_data=validation_generator,nb_val    _samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

Comment: You should use `predict` method: `model.predict(img_array)`. The `img_array` must have a shape of `(num_images, img_width, img_height, 3)` according to your model's input shape.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, you need to load an image and make a prediction:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

img = load_img(filename)
img_array = img_to_array(img)
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)

prediction = model.predict(img_array)
```

I assume this is what you mean by test a model on a single PNG file.